# Using JavaScript, what options are there to set the currently selected navigation item?

Tags: javascript, menu

Using JavaScript, what options are there to set the currently selected navigation item?

Assuming the page refreshes on whenever someone clicks on a navigation link, the only way would be to either do it on the server-side or set it dynamically by looking up the current URL?

Are there any other tricks?

Answer (score 1):

The [`window.location.pathname`](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/prop_loc_pathname.asp) property is reliable, and if you were to use a substring comparison with the href of links in the menu it would be quick (ie no regex testing).

```
var menuLinks = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < menuLinks.length; i++) {
  if (menuLinks[i].href.indexOf(window.location.pathname) > -1) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I set a class attribute on the `<body>` element for my pages, like 'home-section' or 'products-section'.

When the page loads, you can use JavaScript to retrieve the value of the attribute and set the navigation class appropriately.

```
if ($("body").attr("class") == 'home-section') {
    $("li#primary-nav-home").addClass("active");
}
```

You could also accomplish the same thing with straight CSS with the appropriate selector and get rid of the need for classes.

`body.home-section li#primary-nav-home { /* styling rules */ }`